# head и поисковики

Tags: html, seo

Нужно ли писать описания к сайту в "head", или нет разницы поисковики не обращают на него внимания?

Answer (score 1):

в теге `<head>` можно прописать ключевые слова, которые учитывают поисковики при индексации страниц.
кроме того, `<head>` обязателен для того, чтобы Ваша страница считалась валидной. также обязателен `<title>`.

Comment: Так-же желателен `<meta name="description" content="..." />` он используется поисковиками при выводе в списке при определенных условиях, по-хорошему нужно писать туда что-то осмысленное.

Answer (score 1):

title, description, keywords, правильно прописанные в head значительно помогают поисковикам при индексации вашего сайта. Вдобавок, title и description отображаются в результатах поиска.

Answer (score 1):

Если желаете в последствии разработки сайт продвигать, то необходимо писать по максимуму, а именно: title, фавикон, метатеги "og-", следует даже указывать язык страницы в тег html. Ну это уже больше пошла SEO-оптимизация, чем верстка.